Aligning the columns of longtable
I am looking for an explanation to the following piece of code:
\begin{longtable}{*{2}{>{\scriptsize}c>{\scriptsize}p{2cm}}}

This code generates a table that has four columns, two of which are in paragraph (p{}) form. Since I don't know the logic behind this code, I can't extend the logic and use it to create more than four columns.
Additionally, I would love if someone can help me center the header row texts. (For rows that have the p{} form, the header-row-texts being left-aligned look odd since the other header-row-texts are center-aligned.)
Reference: This code was used here.

This is standard tabular preamble syntax as extended by the core latex tools package.
c is a centred column with single line content set its natural width.
p{2cm} is a \parbox[t]{2cm} column with lines breaking to 2cm.
*{2}{abc}  just repeats its argument 2 times so is the same as abcabc.
The above are all standard latex column types defined in the format.  Then the array extension adds
>{...} injects ... into the start of each column, so in this case \scriptsize.
In fact it is unnecessary here as it would be much more efficient and produce more consistent spacing to use
\scriptsize
\begin{longtable}{c p{2cm} c p{2cm}}

and set the whole table at \scriptsize rather than inject `\scriptsize separately into every cell.
You can center a specific cell eg for a header by using
\multicolumn{1}{c}{some text here}

as the \multicolumn then overrides the default column alignment with c.

Thank you Mr. David. Answered my questions perfectly.
